# Authenticating with Azure AD application SPN

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

I have been trying to authenticate via Azure AD application SPN but it throws me error stating:

```
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '\60157752-a19e-xxxx-b27b-c9386e904fce' was not found in the directory c25f4xxx-da2a-4bd5-xxxx-d6407e8767ab
```

I have followed these articles for setting up SPN for authentication:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/

This is my PS for setting up a new application:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$azureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication  -DisplayName "vso.1.1" -HomePage "https://fakeurl.com" -IdentifierUris "https://fakeurl.com" -Password "xxx"
$azureAdApplication 
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId.Guid
```

If I login to portal, I can see the new application added under default directory. If I login from PS it fails. Here is my login script:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName 60157752-a19e-4133-b27b-c9386e904fxe -Message 'enter pwd'
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -ServicePrincipal -Tenant (Get-AzureRmContext).Tenant.TenantId -SubscriptionId 'x8366484-6abd-4741-a9c9-d693880d12x1'
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code where you are trying to authenticate using the SPN.

Comment: Does `(Get-AzureRmContext).Tenant.TenantId` return the tenantId you expect?  I'm not sure what the behavior of `Get-AzureRmContext` is when called before `Login-AzureRmAccount`.

Comment: Yes it gives me correct tenantId.